# Oracle CASE WHEN - ORA-00936: missing expression

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am new to oracle and below is my SQL.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE COLUMN1 = 'YES'
AND COLUMN2 IN (


CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE COLUMN1 = 'YES' AND COLUMN2 NOT LIKE '%NO%') 
 THEN 
   SELECT COLUMN2 FROM TABLE1 WHERE COLUMN1 = 'YES' AND COLUMN2 NOT LIKE '%YES%'
 ELSE 
   SELECT COLUMN2 FROM TABLE1 WHERE COLUMN1 = 'YES' AND COLUMN2 NOT LIKE '%YES%'  END)
```

it is giving  ORA-00936: missing expression at then statement. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you are only evaluating exists you shouldn't return the entire data set. Consider using something like this: `CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 'TRUE' FROM TABLE1...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The subqueries after `THEN` and `ELSE` must be enclosed inside parentheses:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE COLUMN1 = 'YES'
AND COLUMN2 IN (
  CASE 
    WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE COLUMN1 = 'YES' AND COLUMN2 NOT LIKE '%NO%') 
      THEN (SELECT COLUMN2 FROM TABLE1 WHERE COLUMN1 = 'YES' AND COLUMN2 NOT LIKE '%YES%')
    ELSE (SELECT COLUMN2 FROM TABLE1 WHERE COLUMN1 = 'YES' AND COLUMN2 NOT LIKE '%YES%')
  END
)
```

This will work only if these subqueries don't return more than 1 row.
Also, both subqueries are the same. Is this a typo?
And `IN` can be changed to `=` since `CASE` returns only 1 value.

Comment: How can I write this if it returns more than 1 row? Can I use IF ExISTS?

Comment: You can't. CASE returns only 1 value

Comment: Okay, Can I use EXISTS ? and returns multiple values ?

Comment: EXISTS returns TRUE or FALSE. It does not return rows.

Comment: After checking exists, can we write then and else ?

Comment: Then and else are parts of a case statement.

Comment: then what is the best way to do this ?

Comment: This answer is about the syntax error you mention in your question. If you solved this problem and you have another requirement post another question where you explain what you want to do.

Comment: I posted here. Please check the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58087576/oracle-if-exists

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58087576/oracle-if-exists-then-else Did you see this ?

Comment: I did and you did not explain what you want to do, neither posted sample data and expected results. So it is not clear what you want to do.